# How to see the current user's queue in SLURM

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, slurm, supercomputers, loadleveler

On a cluster that is managed by SLURM, I want to check the queue of the current user (and cluster). Normally, I have to use this command:

```
squeue --user=username --clusters=clustername
```

The problem with this, apart from the fact that this is a rather long command to use frequently, is that it needs the username. I have created a script in which at some point I want to check the queue of the user, but I have to get the username first.

I have a workaround for all these, but it would be great if I could use a command like the respective one for LoadLeveller:

```
llu
```

Is there anything like that? Or can I somehow specify the "current user" in the `--user` flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use an alias in the */etc/bashrc* file (or *~/.bashrc* for some users):

```
alias llu="squeue --user=$USER --clusters=clustername"
```

**EDIT**

You could also use this alias which does not depend on an environment variable:

```
alias llu="squeue --user=`whoami` --clusters=clustername"
```

or

```
alias llu="squeue --user=`logname` --clusters=clustername"
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of using the $USER variable, thanks! How much portable is it? Do also shells other than bash use the same variable?

Comment: If you are worried about portably. you might want to use a command instead of an environment variable (I've made some changes in my answer ).

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `squeue -u $LOGNAME`. If you want to query for the jobs on the current cluster it should be the default behavior without having to add the `--clusters` parameter, so this way the squeue command becomes simplier.

According to this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76369, $LOGNAME should always be defined in the environment, so this should be completely portable.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of slurm accept

```
squeue --me
```

as a [shortcut](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html#OPT_me).

Comment: Which version is the newer one? is it `22-05`?

Comment: The 22.05 has `scancel --me` which is new, but `squeue --me` appeared in 20.02